# ubuntu 16.04 doesn't recognise wireless card after a while

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, internet

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 along with Windows in a dual boot. I have an HP Pavillion dv6000 with an Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection and my driver is iwl3945. Even on my first try to boot Ubuntu the sign on the wifi sign blinks from red to blue, which is a sign that my internet connection is not stable. After a while, I lost Internet connection completely(even wired one) the WiFi sign is now constantly red.

However, the sign up and right of the screen still shows I have Internet. If I switch off the WiFi switch and then switch it on again,it shows no **enable wifi** option(in fact I cannot select it).

Please do you have any idea? No matter how much I've searched on the Internet I couldn't find something helpful. I'm new on ubuntu so please be lenient.

Here is the output of the `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [103c:135c]
Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
Kernel modules: iwl3945
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.       
RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion dv6700 [103c:30cc]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following first:

```
sudo rmmod -f iwl3945
sudo modprobe iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=0
```

If it solves the problem, run the following to make it permanent:

```
echo "options iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Donload `iwlwifi-3945-ucode-15.32.2.9.tgz` from [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlegacy?s[]=iwl3945):

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-3945-ucode-15.32.2.9.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-3945-ucode-15.32.2.9.tgz
cd iwlwifi-3945-ucode-15.32.2.9
```

Copy the firmeware to your `/lib/firmware`:

```
cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Reload the driver:

```
modprobe -r iwl3945
modprobe iwl3945
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try to copy the firmware it says `cp: cannot create regular file '/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode': Permission denied`

Comment: Run it with `sudo`.

Comment: OK I did that but nothing changes. It seems that it cannot recognise `modprobe iwl3945` after `modprobe -r iwl3945`. But I ran `rfkill unblock all` and the switcher turns to constantly blue, instead of constantly red. But it still says at the networks settings that the device is not ready. Any idea?