# WiFi turns off in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

Ever since I installed Ubuntu on my laptop about 2 weeks ago, the WiFi randomly goes off and the only way (that I've figured) to solve the issue is by restarting my computer.

However, I am getting a bit annoyed with this especially if I'm working on a document or something of that sort. Also, when that happens, the "enable networking" and the "enable wifi" boxes are both checked. I've tried unchecking and rechecking them, but it's still the same anyways.

Any suggestions/solutions?

**Edit #1:** Result of:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [103c:135b]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
    Kernel modules: iwl3945
--
05:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection [8086:1092] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/100 VE Network Connection [103c:30bb]
    Kernel driver in use: e100
    Kernel modules: e100
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: This did not work for me; neither did the workarounds in http://askubuntu.com/questions/808175/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-recognise-wireless-card-after-a-while/835412#835412 I posted some additional information in that other thread. If someone has a solution, please help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should disable `power management`. Open terminal by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run following commands one by one

```
    sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
    sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
    sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

If it works, make it permanent [by putting it into script](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1686641.html) or [through pm-utils](https://askubuntu.com/a/85223/295286).

If that didn't solve your problem than `disable n`

If you have intel type of wireless card, you might want to [try disabling n-wireless](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is quite unlikely that, in Ubuntu 16.04 and later, `wlan0` is his interface.

Comment: For me, sudo ifconfig wlan0 down, sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off

Comment: I too have this problem with a Dell latitude D630.  Has wlan1 become more canonical for some reason?  I will try these commands and report back.   lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1673] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [1028:01f9]
 Kernel modules: tg3
3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:1020]
 Kernel driver in use: iwl3945