# My WiFi working for finite time

Tags: networking, drivers

I have an Aspire 5 with Ubuntu, I use it normaly but suddenly my WiFi turns off and it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found", you can see the driver in the image: [Wi-Fi driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRJIY.png)

As you can see it says Not using device, but I can't change that option, Ihave installed a propietary driver but it didn't solve the prblem.

Thank you

Comment: I think it's about to power managment. Here is the answer, can you try?
[Power Managment for Wifi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently)

Comment: So far it seems to be working, thank you very much!

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/811311/757695. Anyway, if you want to mention somebody, use @ before their username. @ErickMunive